# How to wait in the main thread until all worker threads have completed in Qt?

Tags: multithreading, qt

I have designed an application which is running 20 instance of a thread.

```
for(int i = 0;i<20;i++)
{
    threadObj[i].start();
}
```

How can I wait in the main thread until those 20 threads finish?

Answer (score 8):

You need to use [`QThread::wait()`.](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qthread.html#wait)

> ### bool QThread::wait ( unsigned long time = ULONG_MAX )
>
> Blocks the thread until either of
> these conditions is met:
>
> - The thread associated with this
>   *QThread* object has finished execution (i.e. when it returns from
>   *run()*). This function will return true if the thread has finished. It
>   also returns true if the thread has
>   not been started yet.
> - *time* milliseconds has elapsed. If time is
>   *ULONG_MAX* (the default), then the wait
>   till never timeout (the thread must
>   return from *run()*). This function
>   will return *false* if the wait timed
>   out.
>
> This provides similar functionality to
> the POSIX *pthread_join()* function.

Just loop over the threads and call *wait()* for each one.

```
for(int i = 0;i < 20;i++)
{ 
    threadObj[i].wait(); 
}
```

If you want to let the main loop run while you're waiting. (E.g. to process events and avoid rendering the application unresponsible.) You can use the signals & slots of the threads. *QThread*'s got a *finished()* singal which you can connect to a slot that remembers which threads have finished yet.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use QWaitCondition

Answer (score 1):

What Georg has said is correct. Also remember you can call signal slot from across threads. So you can have your threads emit a signal to you upon completion. SO you can keep track of no of threads that have completed their tasks/have exited. This could be useful if you don't want your Main thread to go in a blocking call wait.